# PostgreSQL COPY from CSV with delimiter "|"

Tags: postgresql

please, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I'd like to create a table in Postgres database with data from CSV file with delimiter "|", while trying to use the command COPY (or Import) I get this error:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY twitter, line 2: ""Sono da Via Martignacco 
http://t.co/NUC6MP0z|"<a href=""http://foursquare.com"" rel=""nofollow"">f..."
```

The first 2 lines of CSV:

```
txt|"source"|"ulang"|"coords"|"tweettime_wtz"|"country"|"id"|"userid"|"in_reply_user_id"|"in_reply_status_id"|"uname"|"ucreationdate"|"utimezone"|"followers_count"|"friends_count"|"x_coords"|"y_coords"
Sono da Via Martignacco http://t.co/NUC6MP0z|"<a href=""http://foursquare.com"" rel=""nofollow"">foursquare</a>"|"it"|"0101000020E6100000191CA9E7726F2A4026C1E1269F094740"|"2012-05-13 10:00:45+02"|112|201582743333777411|35445264|""|""|"toffo93"|"2009-04-26 11:00:03"|"Rome"|1044|198|13.21767353|46.07516943
```

For this data I have created in Postgres a table "Twitter"

```
CREATE TABLE public.twitter
(
  txt character varying(255),
  source character varying(255),
  ulang character varying(255),
  coords geometry(Point,4326),
  tweettime_wtz character varying(255),
  country integer,
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  in_reply_user_id character varying(255),
  in_reply_status_id character varying(255),
  uname character varying(255),
  ucreationdate character varying(255),
  utimezone character varying(255),
  followers_count integer,
  friends_count integer,
  x_coords numeric,
  y_coords numeric,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.twitter
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination table contain 16 column, but your file contain have 17 column.

It seems to be the `id` field who is missing.

try to set you table as:

```
CREATE TABLE public.twitter
(
  txt character varying(255),
  source character varying(255),
  ulang character varying(255),
  coords geometry(Point,4326),
  tweettime_wtz character varying(255),
  country integer,
id character varying,
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  in_reply_user_id character varying(255),
  in_reply_status_id character varying(255),
  uname character varying(255),
  ucreationdate character varying(255),
  utimezone character varying(255),
  followers_count integer,
  friends_count integer,
  x_coords numeric,
  y_coords numeric,
  CONSTRAINT twitter_pk PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Change the data type of the `id` field as you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!! You are right I missed the id column, but also I have found out that the problem was in my CSV file. I'll explain the rest of solution below.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

So the problem was in my CSV file: it has had invisible signs of quotes. I haven't seen them when I opened CSV in Excel, I saw the lines in this way:

```
txt|"source"|"ulang"|"coords"|"tweettime_wtz"|"country"|"id"|"userid"|"in_reply_user_id"|"in_reply_status_id"|"uname"|"ucreationdate"|"utimezone"|"followers_count"|"friends_count"|"x_coords"|"y_coords"
Sono da Via Martignacco http://t.co/NUC6MP0z|"<a href=""http://foursquare.com"" rel=""nofollow"">foursquare</a>"|"it"|"0101000020E6100000191CA9E7726F2A4026C1E1269F094740"|"2012-05-13 10:00:45+02"|112|201582743333777411|35445264|""|""|"toffo93"|"2009-04-26 11:00:03"|"Rome"|1044|198|13.21767353|46.07516943
```

But when I opened CSV in notepad I saw it differently:

```
"txt"|"source"|"ulang"|"coords"|"tweettime_wtz"|"country"|"id"|"userid"|"in_reply_user_id"|"in_reply_status_id"|"uname"|"ucreationdate"|"utimezone"|"followers_count"|"friends_count"|"x_coords"|"y_coords"
"Sono da Via Martignacco http://t.co/NUC6MP0z"|"<a href=""http://foursquare.com"" rel=""nofollow"">foursquare</a>"|"it"|"0101000020E6100000191CA9E7726F2A4026C1E1269F094740"|"2012-05-13 10:00:45+02"|112|201582743333777411|35445264|""|""|"toffo93"|"2009-04-26 11:00:03"|"Rome"|1044|198|13.21767353|46.07516943
"
```

So i should delete all quotes (in Notepad and saving the file as CSV), so that the text became:

```
txt|source|ulang|coords|tweettime_wtz|country|id|userid|in_reply_user_id|in_reply_status_id|uname|ucreationdate|utimezone|followers_count|friends_count|x_coords|y_coords
Sono da Via Martignacco http://t.co/NUC6MP0z|<a href=http://foursquare.com rel=nofollow>foursquare</a>|it|0101000020E6100000191CA9E7726F2A4026C1E1269F094740|2012-05-13 10:00:45+02|112|201582743333777411|35445264|||toffo93|2009-04-26 11:00:03|Rome|1044|198|13.21767353|46.07516943
```

Only after this I was able to use Import tool in pgAdmin without any problem!